# Installation problems concerning available drive space

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

I'm trying to replace my windows 10 system with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (not partition my hard drive). I have 426 GB of space available per my C drive on Windows. When I boot my computer using Ubuntu USB and click on 'install Ubuntu' it says that I need at least 8.4 GB of drive space and only have 8.2 GB available. What is this number actually referring to ? Any help with this installation would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Kayla Amherst

Comment: Have you tried wiping the hard disk from the live USB before attempting to install? P.S. You know that if you replace Windows, all your files will be history, right?

Comment: @AndroidDev Yes, I understand that. How do I wipe the hard disk from the live USB ?

Answer (score 0):

(For some reason commenting doesnt work :/ )

You will have to re-format your hard drive to a filesystem that linux can use.

Gparted is a great tool for this. Once you have 
booted into your live USB connect to the internet, open up a terminal and type in "sudo apt-get install gparted" after its finished installing simply type in "sudo gparted" into the terminal. This should bring up a partion editor, go ahead and re-format the ntfs partion to ext4, click apply and you're finished.

The partion editor can be a bit confusing at first so just use google if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to delete the partition table before doing it.
If you are using the text mode version, delete and recreate the partition first.